# Calipso install permissions problems

Tags: mongodb, node.js, permissions

Trying to get started with [Calipso](http://calip.so) and this new node.js world, coming from LAMP and Drupal. I've installed MongoDB, nodeJS, and NPM successfully.

Since I need to run `**sudo** calipso site /var/www/sample-site` the permissions really seem to screw things up. The site appears to get created successfully, but nothing else is able to execute. The basic `calipso` command does works fine. However...

- `calipso test` claims expresso can't be found.
- `calipso install` creates a repeated error list a mile long (`EACCES, Permission denied 'npm-debug.log'`)
- `calipso modules list` fails claiming what seems like the site doesn't have it's mongodb module installed, which looks likely.

Hate to give-up this early on such a lovely frontier.
Help Appreciated.

Comment: ok, installed [expresso](https://github.com/visionmedia/expresso); that was easy. ran `sudo calipso install`, which seemed to work. Also, `sudo calipso modules list` works just fine now. 

Guess me only issue now is rearranging my MAMP setup to use /var/www/ rather than /Applications/MAMP/htdocs, which I really should have done some time ago.

Comment: And duh, just needed to run `node app.js` within my site directory to start the app and visit port 3000 on my localhost. Welcome to my getting started day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers inline as comments above...

1. Installed expresso.
2. Used sudo for commands.
3. started up node.js server.